# Cannot resolve a field name with underscores in graphene

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I went through [the documentation](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/quickstart/) of Python graphene, and it worked. Here is the code -

```
from graphene import ObjectType, String, Schema


class Query(ObjectType):
    hello = String(name=String(default_value="stranger"))

    def resolve_hello(root, info, name):
        return f'Hello {name}!'


schema = Schema(query=Query)

query = '{ hello(name: "GraphQL") }'

result = schema.execute(query)

print(result.data['hello'])    # "Hello GraphQL!"
```

However, on changing `hello` to **`some_field`**, and `resolve_hello` to **`resolve_some_field`**, and making **`query = '{ some_field(name: "GraphQL" }'`**, I got the end result as **None**.

Is there a way to work with fields that include underscores in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unaware of how graphene behind the scenes converts snake case to camel case.

Everything was perfect in the schema definition, but the way I called it as a client needed to be changed.

Hence, instead of:

`query = '{ some_field(name: "GraphQL" }'`

... I needed to do:

**`query = '{ someField(name: "GraphQL" }'`**

... because that's how a client side JavaScript would prefer to call it.